# Filtrar datos de df con ponderadores en python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Estoy trabajando con la EPH del INDEC en python, resulta que debo filtrar la base y debo hacerlo teniendo en cuenta los ponderadores o factor de expansión **PONDERA**

Para calcular los ocupados ejecuto la siguiente sentencia

```
df.ocupados = df[(df.ESTADO==1)]
ocupados = df.ocupados['PONDERA'].sum()
```

Dónde **ESTADO** es igual a uno cuando esta ocupado el individuo.
Pero cuando quiero armar una tabla de contingencia no encuentro como puedo tener en cuenta a **PONDERA**

```
tab = df.ocupados.groupby(['CH04','NIVEL_ED'])['P21'].mean()
table = pd.DataFrame(tab)
```

Dónde **CH04** es el sexo si es 1 es hombre y si es igual a 2 es mujer y **NIVEL_ED** es el mayor grado de estudios alcanzados por el individuo.
**P21** es el ingreso que declara el individuo. 
De esta forma no tuve en cuenta los factores de expansión, cómo puedo incluir ese ponderador en las últimas dos lineas ?

En R se podría ejecutar :

```
         dataset <- df %>%
                    filter(ESTADO == 1) %>%
                    group_by(CH04, NIVEL_ED)
                    summarise(Ingreso = weighted.mean(P21, PONDIIO),
                    ocupados = sum(PONDERA))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede solucionar declarando una variable arriba y haciendo la operación necesaria. Luego la agregas a la tabla y en lugar de usar **P21** se usa **INGRESO**

```
INGRESO = df.ocupados['P21']*df.ocupados['PONDIIO']/df.ocupados['PONDIIO']
df.ocupados['INGRESO'] = INGRESO
```